# JSON Object with one id

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a JSON Class which goes like this

```
Namespace PaymentMethod

                        Public Class PaymentMethodItems

                            <JsonProperty("id")>
                            Public Property Id As Integer

                            <JsonProperty("name")>
                            Public Property Name As String

                            <JsonProperty("description")>
                            Public Property Description As String

                            <JsonProperty("status")>
                            Public Property Status As Integer
                        End Class

                        Public Class Data

                            <JsonProperty("payment_method")>
                            Public Property PaymentMethod As PaymentMethodItems()
                        End Class

                        Public Class PaymentMethod

                            <JsonProperty("event_name")>
                            Public Property Event_Name As String

                            <JsonProperty("data")>
                            Public Property Data As Data
                        End Class

                    End Namespace
```

When i want to serialize this JSON object i use someting like this

```
 For Each dr In _dtDelete.Rows
                    row = New JSON.PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodItems
                    Try
                        row.Id = dr("id")
                        row.Name = dr("name") ' This one comment
                        row.Description = dr("opis") ' This one comment
                        row.Status = dr("Skriven") ' This one comment
                        rows.Add(row)
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                Next

                tableData = New JSON.PaymentMethod.Data With {.PaymentMethod = rows.ToArray()}
                Dim data As New JSON.PaymentMethod.PaymentMethod
                data = New JSON.PaymentMethod.PaymentMethod With {.Data = tableData, .Event_Name = "payment_method_delete"}
```

I wonder is there any way to serialize this object i mean json which will have as output only ID in items list. I dont need all of those propertys in output i only need ID.

I commented the lines i wrote above but it still creates me an object with null values for other propertys.

I think i need to change this line

tableData = New JSON.PaymentMethod.Data With {.PaymentMethod = rows.ToArray()}

instead of rows.ToArray i need somehow to tell only ID from those rows.

Comment: One possibility would be to create a [DataTransferObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) which contains only the field(s) you want to deserialize, copy your data and then deserialize this object.

Comment: @pasty this is to much for me to understand. Will look for a simplier solution or create new class

Comment: What is `PaymentMethodItems`?  There isnt actually any serializing going on in the second block, but you may be able to filter it before serializing.  The `PaymentMethod` class appears not to be used.

Comment: The DataTransferObject (sounds complicated, but it is not) is exactly this - a new class, that instead of holding Id, Name, Description (`PaymentMethodItems`) and so on, holds only Id (create a new class `PaymentMethodItemsDTO`). Copy Id from `PaymentMethodItems` to `PaymentMethodItemsDTO` and deserialize `PaymentMethodItemsDTO`.

Comment: @Plutonix I cant touch the classes because i use them on another places while transfering the data. Now i need the data which contain only id. How can i filter it ??? . 
pasty well now it seems a bit understanding it. I will try to do that since im not similar with objects to much

Comment: @pasty if u have free time to make me an example of that it would be really great. I really cant figure out this